# What does "sine" mean?

Tags: terminology, amino-acids

I see the suffix "sine" (seen/sin) a lot, adenosine, cytosine, lysine, tyrosine, etc. Most of where I hear it is in amino acid R groups, but it's usually only the prefix that is recognized as significant.

Comment: Actual suffix is just -ine and it's standard. "s" comes from various (typically greek) words, like tyros - cheese.

Comment: Comparing adenine/adenosine and cytosine/cytidine couldn't the argument be made that the suffix was -osine for these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Textbook of metabolism and metabolic disorders](https://books.google.com/books?id=4M9qAAAAMAAJ&q=%22suffix%20osine%22&dq=%22suffix%20osine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA5oGcpYXZAhWBwVkKHUrqDmcQ6AEIKTAA) (1964):

> The ribosides derived from purines have the suffix -osine; those from pyrimidines, the suffix -idine. The corresponding deoxyribosides, with the exception of thymidine, do not have any such simple designation. Occasionally, instead of, for example, guanine-deoxyriboside, the term deoxy-guanosine is used.

Beyond the more common adenosine and guanosine, there are also:

[inosine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/inosine#section=Top)  and

[xanthosine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/xanthosine#section=Top)

Comment: That's a pretty old reference, but what about lysine? Or, what is lys?

Comment: @JohnJoe I picked an old reference intentionally, because I am interested in when the convention started.  A 2016 book says (page 453)  "For purine bases, the suffix -osine is used (adenosine, guanosine)" https://books.google.com/books?id=HRCdBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA453&dq=%22suffix+-osine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitm7HmlIfZAhVku1kKHZlEA-sQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22suffix%20-osine%22&f=false "Lysine" has an unrelated word origin http://bioetymology.blogspot.com/2012/03/lysine.html

Comment: @JohnJoe see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ine